# get last item of a specific class in markup

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to know how I can find the last item of a specific class inside the markup.

```
<body>
    <elem class="thatelement"></elem>
    <elem></elem>
    <elem class="thatelement"></elem>
    <elem>
        <elem class="thatelement"></elem>
    </elem>
</body>
```

I want to find the last element of `.thatelement` in the markup whether it is a directive `body` child or located elsewhere in nested elements. And please provide me if its crossbrowser working.

Comment: You would have to use JavaScript (or jQuery etc). With just CSS selectors selecting the last element with a specific class is not possible.

Comment: @Harry what would be a jQuery way though?

Comment: @SalmanA this is just an example, the selected element should be the last element with a specific class in any markup!

Comment: AFAIK there is no CSS selector/combinator/trick for selecting the last element of its class. `jQuery(".thatelement:last")` should do the trick though.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aajrzLv6/) is a sample using jQuery (same as what Salman A has mentioned above).

Comment: thanks guys, guess thats fine for me. Could you make an answer, I will accept!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery, the last() function will do the work.

HTML

```
<body>
    <elem class="thatelement">1</elem>
    <elem>2</elem>
    <elem class="thatelement">3</elem>
    <elem>
        <elem class="thatelement">4</elem>
    </elem>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
$( ".thatelement" ).last().css( "color", "red" );
```

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esantos/7d01auno/) so you can view the behavior. The last() function documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/last/)